# batch file pauses if command window not selected

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, jar

I have a .bat-file that executes the following commands:

```
cls 
@pushd %~dp0
@echo off
java -Dmypath=path -jar ./my_directory/myjava_program.jar arg1 arg2
@popd
@pause
```

In addition to that I have this **restraining requirement**: The batch file needs to be executed by clicking on it. No execution with additional commands in the command line is possible.

**The problem:**
The script runs fine if it is executed in the foreground. But as soon as I change to another program, the output in the command window will pause. If I click ENTER in the command window the script will continue again.
What is the reason the script pauses?

- priority given for execution of other program?
- something with the read line support (I read about this issue in a couple of related posts)?
- ...

And what could be a solution to keep the script running even if I don't have the command window selected? (It can still be visible though)

Comment: Your script is really only running a single command, `@start "" /d "%dp0my_directory" cmd.exe /k "java.exe -jar myjava_program.jar arg1 arg2"`. **So try replacing all of your batch file content with that**, _(obviously changing `my_directory` and `myjava_program.jar arg1 arg2` to your real values)_, and see what happens when you run it in the same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click on Command window, select properties, and uncheck "QuickEdit Mode" if it is checked. May have to close/reopen dos window to persist that setting.